# Global minimum of $f(x)=\langle Ax,x \rangle +2 \langle x,b \rangle+c$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, maxima-minima, positive-definite

Given that $A\in M_n(\Bbb R)$ is a symmetric positive-definite matrix, $b \in \Bbb R^n , c\in \Bbb R$ I need to find the global minimum of the function 
$$ f(x) =\langle Ax,x \rangle +2 \langle x,b \rangle + c.$$

To solve this I first wanted to solve $D_f(a)=0$ ($D_f(a)$ is the differential of $f$ at point $a$).

> In order to find a local minimum, then show it is also global. But it seems like a lot of work if I define $A=(a)_{ij}$. Is there a shorter/better way?

Comment: Have you tried completing the square?

Comment: I didn't learn how to do that actually. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Suppose you knew that $f(x) = \|Bx-d\|^2 + e$ for some matrix $B$ and vector $d$ and number $e$. Then you can read off the answer to your question in terms of $B$ and $d$.  Completing the square is a way of finding $B, d, e$ from $A, b, c$.

Comment: Would it help if you solved it first for a diagonal matrix with positive values on the diagonal... then solve the general case by diagonalising the matrix $A $ ?

Answer (score 1):

> **First Method: Completing the square**

Indeed, it using the fact that $A$ is symmetric, positive definite and invertible we have

\begin{align}0&\le \langle A(\color{red}{x+A^{-1}b}),\color{red}{x+A^{-1}b} \rangle \\&=\langle Ax,x \rangle+\langle Ax,A^{-1}b \rangle+ \langle b,x \rangle+\langle b,A^{-1}b \rangle \\&=\langle Ax,x \rangle+2\langle b,x \rangle+\langle b,A^{-1}b \rangle\\&=f(x) \color{blue}{-c+ \langle b,A^{-1}b\rangle} \end{align}

Thus for all $x\in \Bbb R^n$ we have, 
$$
 f(x)\ge \color{blue}{c- \langle b,A^{-1}b\rangle} =\color{red}{f(-A^{-1}b)} 
$$
Whence, $$\color{blue}{\min_{x\in\Bbb R^n} f(x) =-\langle A^{-1}b,b \rangle+ c}$$

> **Second Method: By Calculus** From here [Differentiating $\langle Ax,x\rangle$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994574/differentiating-langle-ax-x-rangle?rq=1) we have, $$Df(x)h = \langle Ax , h \rangle + \langle Ah , x \rangle+2b\cdot  h\\= 2\langle Ax , h \rangle +2b\cdot h$$

since A is symmtric 
Thus, $$Df(x)= 2 Ax +2b $$

$$Df(x)= 0\Longleftrightarrow  \color{red}{x= -A^{-1}b}$$

Moreover, since A is positive definite we get that the Hessian, 
 $$D^2f(x)(h,h) = 2\langle Ah , h \rangle\ge 0$$

> Hence,$ \color{red}{x= -A^{-1}b}$ is the only critical point of $f$ and the Hessian is  positive definite. This  means that, 
>   the global minimum of $f$ is attained at $ \color{red}{x= -A^{-1}b}$
>   hence,

$$\min f(x)=f( \color{red}{ -A^{-1}b}) =\langle AA^{-1}b,A^{-1}b \rangle -2 \langle A^{-1}b,b \rangle+c = -\langle A^{-1}b,b \rangle +c$$
That is 
$$\color{blue}{\min_{x\in\Bbb R^n} f(x) =-\langle A^{-1}b,b \rangle+ c}$$

Comment: The linear term is $2b$ not $b$, which will change your results.

Comment: @greg thanks a lot that made a huge difference in the answer

Comment: why did somebody downvotes this post?

Comment: Your answer lacks clarity. You should write somewhere that for any $x\in \mathbb R^n$, the Hessian matrix at $x$ is $2A$ which is positive definite, so $f$ is **convex**. Therefore, **any** critical point of $f$ achieves a **global minimum**.

Comment: PS: I didn't downvote.

Comment: @GabrielRomon I understand what you mean but the convexity here is pointless. Since for any function that Hessian is positive definite at in a neighborhood of a critical point $a$ possess  $a$ as a local minimum . (unless you have a counterexample but I know this from calculus.) In the  present cases the critical point is unique so it is the Global minimum. I don,t what is wrong?

Comment: @GabrielRomon have a look to the new EDIT propose to way to solve the problem both leading to the same answer.

Comment: "the critical point is unique so it is the Global minimum". This statement is wrong. You don't know a priori if a global minimum exists. There are plenty of functions with a unique local minimum but no global minimum. Either you prove first that a global minimum exists (by proving that $f$ is [coercive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coercive_function#.28Extended_valued.29_coercive_functions)) or you use directly that $f$ is convex.

Comment: @GabrielRomon What is wrong there? before I said the Hessian matrix is positive definite . read it in the post.   $$,$$                                                 There are plenty of functions .....no global minimum" where does this apply in my answer. I even prove at the first place that the Hessian is positive definite. Here the resume of what I have written: "Hessian Positive definite + unique critical point $\implies $ Global minimum. you may try to contradict this I will see.

Comment: Are you of good faith ? You proved that the "Hessian is positive definite". That's not even a precise statement. The Hessian evaluated at which point ? If you mean "the Hessian **at the critical point** is positive definite", then your argument is flawed. Because "there are plenty of functions with a unique local minimum but no global minimum". If you mean "the Hessian **at every point** is positive definite", you've proven that **$f$ is convex**. But you wrote in your own comment that "the convexity here is pointless". Your reasoning is flawed, be of good faith and admit it.

Comment: "You proved that the "Hessian is positive definite". That's not even a precise statement. The Hessian evaluated at which point ?" The Hessian is positive definite no matter the point.  Do you know the definition of positive definite? for the rest I don't know what you are trying to prove. But instead give a contradiction rather than philosophizing.

Comment: "The Hessian is positive definite no matter the point." Hence $f$ is convex, hence any critical point is a global minimum. That's a valid reasoning. But yours is plain wrong. Since you're exhibiting bad faith, I'll stop there.

Comment: @GabrielRomon 1-I don't need  convexity. 2- It is now that you realize that the Hessian i positive definite no matter the point. 3-clear proof that you did read the ealier version of my post. 4- Please I would like now to know is the problem with what is written in my post? you still did not clarify that point.  5 - you are fully and Totally right. are you satisfy ?

Comment: A remark. $2Ax+2b$ is not the derivative $Df(x)$ but the gradient $\nabla f(x)$.

Comment: that is a matter of notation . French notation vs English